# Jpa Conversion failed string to uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Spring Boot: 2.0.2

Hibernate Core: 5.2.17

dialect: SQLServer2012Dialect

When trying to save entity whose id is a generated GUID into SQL Server
using JpaRepository save() method the operation fails with the following messages:

> SQL Error: 8169, SQLState: S0002
>
> Conversion failed when converting from a character string to
>   uniqueidentifier
>
> HHH000327: Error performing load command :
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not load an entity
>
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed
>   when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "guid", parameters = {})
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator" , strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "ActivityID" , columnDefinition="uniqueidentifier")
private String ActivityID;
```

Another description of the problem: [Conversion failed from a character string to uniqueidentifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024506/insert-fails-when-trying-to-retrieve-the-inserted-row)

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some digging, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25634443/2383797) is what solved it for me:

Basically change the mapping to:

```
    private UUID id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column( columnDefinition = "uuid", updatable = false )
    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }
```

And don't forget to send a (not) friendly email to the DBA that decided to use that id type -.-

Regards